# how to save private key for android cordova app

Tags: android, cordova

Let's imagine an android/phonegap app that connects with a server for data. I want to use some private key, so that you can use the API from the server only if you have the app.

I found there is a plugin for ios called keychain, but have not found something similar for android. Now, this must be a solved problem. A lot of apps use API's to servers on android. How do you solve this?

My main objective is not generating private keys, but keeping the servers private (for those that have the app). If the way to go is to generate a private key (which is what I thought at first), then I cannot find a way to save a private key securely when using phonegap on android. The closes I've got is putting it on javascript and obfuscating the code.

I found the android keystore, but if I understand correctly that's for cryptography which I don't need.

Comment: By "private key" do you mean the private key of a RSA key-pair? If not what is the usage of the "private key"? Keys are part of cryptography, so use the keystone. Also, when is the "private key" generated, at compile-time or later in the app?

Comment: No, I didn't mean a private key of a RSA key-pair. I meant just a private variable, call it password or key. Maybe I'm missing something obvious like how to use a RSA key-pair to do what I want, keeping the api private.

Comment: The usual terminology for a symmetric encryption key is "secret key". If not for encryption perhaps an API key. gain: when is the "private key" generated, at compile-time or later in the app? Also define the attacker and the value of what is being protected.

Comment: At compile time. I want to save such api key so the server knows   that whoever is making the request actually has the app

Answer (score 0):

It is virtually impossible to secure a compile-time key, it is in the code. Securing it from a the user is even more difficult.

Depending on the platform the executable may be available to viewing by examining the file. Other platforms, including iOS, encrypt the executable and is not available until execution time.

Obfuscation may be your best approach but understand that it is only increases the work factor minimally.

Saving the key in a keychain or keystone does not really help in protecting from the user, the user has access and the key is still in the code.

Also you need to use https with a current server configuration and pin the certificate.

If you need better security consider creating a key at first run or requiring the user to log-in.